# Issue with puppeteer cluster scripts in AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

I'm facing issue in page loading when running through puppeteer(puppeteer-cluster) scripts in AWS EC2 Instance. But the same is working when I m opening manually in EC2. Also, puppeteer scripts working perfectly in local machines both Headless true/false.
Is there any memory issue? Please help

Note: Able to login into the application and navigating to pages. But the issue is only at specific page/content loading. Even kept explicit wait of 3 mins and took a screenshot(seeing blank/white page) after a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, actually application requires proxy in the EC2 machine. By setting up it works fine now.

Comment: What do mean by "application requires proxy in the EC2 machine"? And how did you set that up?